# OpenScholar virtual subdomain

Tags: php, drupal, subdomain, virtual

I installed OpenScholar in my domain:

http://scholar.web

Basically, when someone register for an account, his site URL is http://scholar.web/user, and his content will be at http://scholar.web/user/contents

I've been searching a way so that the URL is converted into: http://user.scholar.web/content for displaying his content via virtual subdomain (htaccess maybe)

Anyone can provide some solutions or guidance?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to change the DNS entry on the domain so that *.scholar.web points to your site.
Afterwards, (If you're using Apache) change the Apache vhost to accept *.scholar.web requests.
You can then use htaccess and/or PHP to do what you like with the URL formatting.

I used to have a domain called something along the lines of "iscool.com".
This is the method I used so I could use pseudo subdomains like "ben.iscool.com" and it would display content accordingly.

Comment: Well, using the code provided in above URL (removing the string 'something'), when I access: user.scholar.web, I got redirected to scholar.web/user. I think that's a bit okay though. Needs some tweaking so that user.scholar.web not get redirected.